# How do I obtain the TokenID of an ERC721 token through etherscan API transaction? E.g. CryptoKitty TokenID

Tags: etherscan, cryptokitties

I want to be able to find the TokenID of a Crypto Kitty being sold.

The transaction returned from by the etherscan API is such:

```
{
  blockNumber: '11711690',
  timeStamp: '1611403229',
  hash: '0x8f8d4e163e90c8db91672f443b0896f157d45fc32c3ccf74d131137eedbdd896',
  nonce: '4',
  blockHash: '0xbdd67604d6cc7844f151a38360753ad96fa234bd9cf199c6cf14317ebb4fd0ad',
  transactionIndex: '147',
  from: '0x65274ae6d0d4f88818b600c4b3435c868f5dad4c',
  to: '0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c',
  value: '2527858781343926',
  gas: '164016',
  gasPrice: '43000000000',
  isError: '1',
  txreceipt_status: '0',
  input: '0x454a2ab3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a5a3',
  contractAddress: '',
  cumulativeGasUsed: '9793966',
  gasUsed: '27036',
  confirmations: '5702'
}
```

By looking at the transaction on etherscan I can see that the TokenID is 587058 - https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc7e09024a41841d6acb5933ab983a68bb4433a94e3167a2a893be3ea4387fad6

However that is not recorded anywhere on the transaction... Is there any way that I can derive the token ID? Or, is there an alternative way that I can find the token programmatically/via API? I intend to use the TokenID to then obtain further information about the particular Kitty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy.

Get the Transfer events from the transaction hash. using tronscan api.

And find the token ID from the event.

You can use this API:  https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&address=0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d&topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

It will give all the latest transactions. You may sort it through it according to  your particular transaction.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks! So what I take from this is that the TokenID is transmitted as event logs against the transaction hash? 

Does this mean I could also obtain the event logs using a library such as web3js?

Comment: Yes you can get Transfer event using web3js and get token ID from it :)

Comment: @Yogesh Next question: how? I can't see anything about token id on the transaction: {
    address: '0x5c5c53D13aD8725cFE551D6E9dB93e9a9D38D78D',
    blockHash: '0x3f546e5caa9142d89dc3a87e7d369ba175629b480840d8bf88bd146f205e62de',
    blockNumber: 6572543,
    logIndex: 5,
    removed: false,
    transactionHash: '0x7de4476522402eb1769fcb93425c63aa0d14a9fbafec6bf2d7dcb7eafc76fb01',
    transactionIndex: 6,
    id: 'log_bb3a4fc6',
    returnValues: Result {},
    event: undefined,
    signature: null,
    raw: { data: '0x', topics: [Array] }
  },

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution using Web3.

Full code:

```
var abi_ = [
        {"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},
                {"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},
                {"indexed":true,"name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],
        "name":"Transfer","type":"event"}
    ];

    const Web3Eth = require('web3-eth')
    const API_KEY = "f3e2ba..."
    const URL = "wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/" + API_KEY
    const web3Eth = new Web3Eth(Web3Eth.givenProvider || URL);
    const smartContractAddress = "0xab6a8c463d7fecd3ab65761769b7ccbb83ecb597"
    const contract = new web3Eth.Contract(abi_, smartContractAddress)

    contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {
            fromBlock: 0,
            toBlock: 'latest'
        }, function(error, events){
            if(!error){
                for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++){
                    console.log(events[i].returnValues.tokenId)
                }
            }
        })
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
```